# What were the goals of the woman's march during Trump's inauguration?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, inauguration, feminism

I've read there was a [2017 Women's March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Women%27s_March) held on the day after President Trump's inauguration in Washington.

It's not clear to me why? What's their motivation? And what goals do they hope to accomplish?

Comment: The march was apparently originally conceived as taking place during the inauguration, but in the end it was held the next day.

Comment: The questions above are so general they might as well be about *any* march.  If the OP *doesn't know why* any political march happens, the question may be made more general, (with the 2017 Women's March as an example thereof).  Or, if the OP *does understand* why political marches occur, the questions above should be made more specific regarding what interests him about this particular march.

Comment: Stated or unstated goals?

Answer (score 13):

According to Wikipedia, their Goals are as follows:

> Protection of our rights, our safety, our health, and our families – recognizing that our vibrant and diverse communities are the strength of our country

Their reason for marching was to raise awareness.

Wikipedia continues:

> The 2017 Women's Marches were a series of political rallies that took place in cities around the world since January 21, 2017, with the goal of promoting women's rights, immigration reform, and health care reform; to counter Islamophobia, rape culture, and LGBTQ abuse; and to address racial inequities (e.g., Black Lives Matter), workers' issues, and environmental issues. The rallies largely targeted Donald Trump, the recently-inaugurated President of the United States, as well as many of his statements and positions which had been deemed anti-women or otherwise reprehensible

i.e. it can be viewed as a protest against Trump's quick removal of any mentions on LGBT rights on the US. Govt. official website, www.usa.govt. One can assume that it comes as a reaction to him being elected President, even if he is a self-proclaimed women-groper. You can read and watch on several sites, here is the first google result:

http://www.slate.com/blogs/the_slatest/2016/10/07/donald_trump_2005_tape_i_grab_women_by_the_pussy.html

Whether you agree with their cause or not, they have every right to express themselves, just like you do.

Comment: I would say that `Trump's quick removal of any mentions on LGBT` can not be considered as a reason to organize the march because it had to be organized way before the removal was done. Of course, such a removal can be interpreted as a sign that the worries of the organizers and people attending the march are justified.

Comment: @SJuan76 surely you are correct that the initial actions of the Trump administration were not reasons for organizing the march, but many of the marchers were aware of these actions by the time the march began, and their protests were in part directed against those actions.

Comment: @SJuan76 It might not be a reason for the march itself, but it might be one of the reasons people showed up to it, as phoog sais.

Comment: But references to LGBT haven't been removed from usa.gov - https://search.usa.gov/search/docs?affiliate=usagov&dc=7&query=lgbt They were removed from whitehouse.gov, by the Obama administration as part of the transition so that Trumps staff can fill it with content specific to this administration.

Comment: It would be helpful if this answer both linked to its sources and quoted some form of official statements by the organizers rather than Wikipedia, which has a good chance of being poorly sourced or unsourced for something as recent, high-profile and political as this.  Additionally, while the closing comment may have been warranted for the original question, it seems very accusatory compared to the edited question and ought to be removed.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian the original question was pretty much garbage. I welcome you to edit my answer if you find other sources that are more suitable, and/or if my answer is "too direct." I am norwegian, and even if that doesn't excuse my wording, I hope it shines some light on my "directness." It is a part of my culture. I am sorry if this makes you uncomfortable, or if it comes off as harsh. It was not my intent.

Answer (score 2):

According to their website - as seen here: https://www.womensmarch.com/mission/ - they say,

> In the spirit of democracy and honoring the champions of human rights, dignity, and justice who have come before us, we join in diversity to show our presence in numbers too great to ignore. The Women’s March on Washington will send a bold message to our new government on their first day in office, and to the world that women's rights are human rights. We stand together, recognizing that defending the most marginalized among us is defending all of us.

Interesting to note is they claim to be for all women but made this tweet - https://twitter.com/womensmarch/status/821112766052401153/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw - after barring a women's group who didn't comply with their political platform. Reading the Twitter thread shows they removed other groups who also didn't agree with their entire political platform so their stated goals of the march may be in question.